# How to integrate c++ project in Golang?

Tags: c++, c, go, swig, cgo

The project contains several modules having several header files, uses -std=c++20.
I have tried examples from cgo and SWIG and they compile as expected but for some reason I'm unable to get this project to work.

My project structure is similar to following:

```
.
├───cpp_project
|    ├───external
|    │    └───lib_a
|    │        └───ex_module
|    │            ├───ab
|    │            |    ├───a.h
|    │            |    ├───a.cpp
|    │            |    ├───b.h
|    │            |    └───b.cpp
|    │            └───pq
|    │                 ├───p.h
|    │                 ├───p.cpp
|    │                 ├───q.h
|    │                 └───q.cpp
|    └───src
|        ├───module_a
|        |    ├───x.h
|        |    └───x.cpp
|        ├───module_b
|        |    ├───sub_mod_a
|        |    ├───sub_mod_b
|        |    ├───b.h
|        |    └───b.cpp
|        ├───proj.h
|        ├───proj.cpp
|        ├───wrap.h      // added by me
|        └───wrap.cpp    // added by me
|
├───shared.so
├───main.go
└───go.mod
```

I have created a wrapper, wrap.h and wrap.cpp which contains a function "void foo()", that uses the functions from the project.

- I tried to build a shared object (shared.so), load it in python and call the function "foo". It runs as expected.
- I'm unable to do the same in go. I'm using cgo but the `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lshared` is unable to find shared. Both "main.go" and "shared.so" are in the project directory.
- Also, sometimes it shows error regarding "<iostream>", probably because it is a cpp library.

Also, I would like to compile the project into one single build instead of having the dll/so.

[ I have no experience working with swig and cpp (besides the basics) ]